# How to delete a hdfs file from node.js

Tags: node.js, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I have the following file  in  hdfs

```
hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/direccionbikes.out
```

I wrote a process in node.js and I need to delete this file. I use the api webhdfs.

I use createReadStream and createWriteStream in this program. But I don't know how to delete this file from node.js

Where can I read information about this question(webhdfs)

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the APIs here - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html

**Submit a HTTP DELETE request**.

```
curl -i -X DELETE "http://<host>:<port>/webhdfs/v1/<path>?op=DELETE
                              [&recursive=<true|false>]"
```

The client receives a response with a boolean JSON object:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"boolean": true}
```

Comment: Post relevant APIs in your answer as these link may broken in future